# Algorithm for group scales

Tags: algorithm, math, highcharts, scale

I have a highchart (chart with multiple vertical axes) and I want to group chart universally. Now it is separated only by special data in code. For example:

- scale 1 is about 3.0 and contains only one chart with max value 2.5
- scale 2 is about 2000 and contains three charts with max value 1200,
  1500, 1650
- scale 3 is about 10000 and contains two charts with max
  value 9000 and 8200

What algorithm for grouping can I use in every case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an algorithm that takes a number of values (different things to plot) and sorts them into groups (grouping things plotted on the same scale together). There is a similar situation when you are producing those colored maps that show e.g. how rich different areas are, only they are dividing areas into groups, not different things into groups. One algorithm used for this is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization - I don't think it's particularly great, but people do use it and it is explained nicely in the article.

You could also solve this problem with dynamic programming, where you have a cost function so e.g. if you plot a graph with a maximum value of 1000 using a scale with maximum value 1500 you have a cost of (1000-1500)^2. Sort the maximum values for the graphs into order and work from left to right. For the first k maximum values, find the best assignment using up to n groups, for n = 1..k. You can derive the answers for k from the answers for k-1.